# Handling Variable Number of Columns Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlw

I am trying to write a list of lists into an excel sheet using pandas
the list looks like:

```
List_of Lists = [ [1,2,3,4],
                  [5,6,7,8],
                  [9,10,11,12],
                  ........,
                ]
```

> The number of these lists inside the main list could go up to a 1000.
>   I also want to label them like colums1, colomns2, until colums100 for
>   instance. on the same sheets. can anyone familiar with pandas help me?
>   as this could be really easy for some?

Comment: Is each sublist going to be of the same length? And do you want to treat sublists as columns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can just pass the list into `pd.DataFrame()` and you will just get NaNs for the values that don't exist.

For example:

```
List_of_Lists = [[1,2,3,4],
                 [5,6,7],
                 [9,10],
                 [11]]
df = pd.DataFrame(List_of_Lists)
print(df)
    0     1    2    3
0   1   2.0  3.0  4.0
1   5   6.0  7.0  NaN
2   9  10.0  NaN  NaN
3  11   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then to get the naming the way you want just use [`pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)

```
df = df.add_prefix('Column')
print(df)
   Column0  Column1  Column2  Column3
0        1      2.0      3.0      4.0
1        5      6.0      7.0      NaN
2        9     10.0      NaN      NaN
3       11      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Now I guess there is the possibility that you also could want each list to be a column. In that case you need to transpose your `List_of_Lists`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip_longest(*List_of_Lists))))
print(df)
   0    1     2     3
0  1  5.0   9.0  11.0
1  2  6.0  10.0   NaN
2  3  7.0   NaN   NaN
3  4  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Yay `add_prefix`!

Comment: That is pretty neat, I didn't even realize that was a function. Much simpler than finding the longest sublist

Comment: Good one! Much better than string concatenation

Comment: @Grr, the lists are actually the colums. for example within `listA =[[1,2],[3,4]]`, I want to get 'column1 =[1,2]` and `column2 = [3,4]` ... can it be done by just converting the list to a dataframe the way you suggested?